# Compile code if the platform is not iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know about **#if UNITY_IOS** to check if the current platform is iOS. But is there a way to check if the platform is **NOT** iOS?

Something like:

```
#if NOT UNITY_IOS
//mycode
#endif
```

I'm currently doing it like this, but it just feels wrong.

```
#if UNITY_IOS
#else
//my code
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to do something if it is not iOS then use `!UNITY_IOS`.

```
#if !UNITY_IOS
//NOT iOS code
#endif
```

You can add else statement to it if you need to do other things when it is iOS. I don't think you do based on your question. You can learn more about C# Preprocessor Directives [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_preprocessor_directives.htm).